# Create new dataframe column with isoweekday from datetime

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

I have this dataframe and I want to make a new column for which day of the week the collisions were on.

```
    collision_date
0   2020-03-14
1   2020-07-26
2   2009-02-03
3   2009-02-28
4   2009-02-09
```

I have tried variations of this but nothing works.

```
 df["day of the week"] = df["collision_date"].isoweekday()

 df["day of the week"] = df["collision_date"].apply(isoweekday)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `collision_date` is datetime we can use [`dt.weekday`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.weekday.html) (+1 to match isoweekday returning 1-7 instead of 0-6):

```
# Convert If needed
df['collision_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['collision_date'])
# Turn into Number
df['day of week'] = df['collision_date'].dt.weekday + 1
```

The slower option with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) is to call [`isoweekday`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday) per date:

```
from datetime import date


# Convert If needed
df['collision_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['collision_date'])
# Call isoweekday per date
df['day of week'] = df['collision_date'].apply(date.isoweekday)
```

`df`:

```
  collision_date  day of week
0     2020-03-14            6
1     2020-07-26            7
2     2009-02-03            2
3     2009-02-28            6
4     2009-02-09            1
```

---

Timing Information via timeit:

Sample Data with 1000 rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'collision_date': pd.date_range(start='now', periods=1000, freq='D')
})
```

`dt.weekday`:

```
%timeit df['collision_date'].dt.weekday + 1
261 µs ± 1.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

`apply`:

```
%timeit df['collision_date'].apply(date.isoweekday)
2.53 ms ± 90.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The former runs much much faster than the apply so I will be using that instead!